# Iterator fails to give me all integers, or am I doing something stupid?

Tags: java, iterator

What is wrong with my program, I don't get all the integers in the output:? Am I doing something wrong?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo7 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
        System.out.println("Before = " + al.size());
        al.add(10);
        al.add(43);
        al.add(32.5);
        al.add(10);
        al.add(null);
        al.add('A');
        al.add("ABC");
        al.add(10.12);
        al.add(true);
        al.add("Hello");
        al.add(600);
        al.add(900);
        /*- Remove All the objects except integer and string:*/

        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            if( itr.next() instanceof  Integer){
                Object obj = itr.next();
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

I am trying to print just the Integer objects, I am able to do via streams and other ways but it does not work for some reason?

Comment: Clarify "it does not work". What do you get? What do you expect to get?

Comment: `Iterator.next()` moves one element forward. You are calling `next()` *twice* within your loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's because u have called itr.next() 2 times. Once in if condition then inside body.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `next()` twice - once inside the `if` condition, and then again in the `if`'s body, meaning you are skipping values. You should call it once per iteration of the loop, store the value returned from it to a local variable, and perform all the operations against it:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = itr.next();
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this code runs across an `Integer`, it's calling `.next()` twice: once in the `if` check, and a second time if the `if` check was successful. This means that the first `Integer` is ignored, and the next value is returned. It also means that depending on the structure of the list, a `NoSuchElementException` could be thrown on the final element, if it tries to read past the end of the list.

While there are more idiomatic ways to accomplish this goal (such as streams or even an enhanced foreach loop), one straightforward fix while using the same approach involves storing the value to a variable. This way, the same value can be used in both the `instanceof` check and the `println` parameter:

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Object next = itr.next();
    if(next instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   while(itr.hasNext()){
        Object value = itr.next();
        if(value instanceof  Integer){
            Object obj = value;
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
```